# Connection between the energy scale when inflation starts, ends, the inflaton mass and the reheating temperature?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

Let's assume inflation starts at some energy scale $E_s$ and ends at $E_e$. Is there anything general (I know there are many inflation models) one can say about the inflaton mass and the reheating temperature once $E_s$ and $E_e$ are fixed? Or if something general isn't possible, maybe something in the most popular models?

Maybe it's possible to compare the situation to the Higss mass, because in some models the Higgs field is regarded as inflaton field. The Higgs mass is of the same order of the vacuum expecation value and the corresponding energy scale when the gauge group breaks.

Comment: Even "the inflaton mass" is not something general. What about N-flation models with many fields driving the expansion? Perhaps you should try to explicitly specify what class of models you're willing to consider.

Comment: @Danu I'm interested in the simplest possible model, i.e. just one inflaton